# Why does Joomla not use private, public and protected keywords?

Tags: php, joomla

I noticed that Joomla uses less secure `var` type for variables in classes

Why is this?

In my own `components,plugins,modules` should I follow this convention or use a more secure private, public and protected keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla's roots are in PHP 4, (and as @Palantir notes, they even still support it!).

It is very difficult to "add" PHP 5's new OOP features like `private` / `public` / `protected` to a complex system like that. There are too many dependencies to be aware of, and too much potential for obscure bugs.

They will probably start appearing in the future when PHP 4 support is dropped (shouldn't be long anymore), and parts of the system undergo a fundamental rewrite.

Comment: So basically it would be OK for me to follow the better php5 option and specifically state in the documentation that the plugin does NOT support php4

Comment: @jax yes, that sounds like the best way to go. PHP 4 is dead and shouldn't be supported any more.

Answer (score 0):

That is to be compatible with PHP4, which does not allow access modifiers and relies on the var keyword. See requirements here: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html, they support PHP4, though they do not recommend it.